# MultiValueDictKeyError when i use select form-control in python django with bootstrap

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-4

When I try to use a select form-control in my template for input some selected value to the views, returns the `MultiValueDictKeyError`, but when I try use the same input without the select fields works without an error.

code with select and returns `MultiValueDictKeyError`:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block main %}

Edit


<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token  %}

    <label for="descricao">Data Inicial:</label>
    <input id="descricao" type="text" name="descricao" value="{{ descricao }}" class="form_datetime" /><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({ format: '03/01/19 08:00' });
    </script>
    <label for="descricao2">Data Final:</label>
    <input id="descricao2" type="text" name="descricao2" value="{{ descricao2 }}" class="form_datetime" /><br>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({ format: '03/01/19 09:00' });
    </script>
    <label for="inputUnidades">Selecione unidade</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="inputUnidades" name="inputUnidades">
    {% for item_unidade in unidade2 %}
    <option value="{{ item_unidade }}">{{ item_unidade }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    <input type="submit">



    {% if descricao != None %}
    <br><br>
    <p>

        Data Inicial: {{ descricao }}<br>
        Data Final: {{ descricao2 }}<br>
        Unidade:{{ item_unidade }}
        Tabela:{{ passar|safe }}


    </p>
    {% endif %}

    <a href="{% url 'graficos' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Grafico2</a>
    <a href="{% url 'tela_graficos' %}" class="btn btn-primary">Grafico</a>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

Code that does not return error, I just change this part:

```
 <label for="inputUnidades">Selecione unidade</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="inputUnidades" name="inputUnidades">
    {% for item_unidade in unidade2 %}
    <option value="{{ item_unidade }}">{{ item_unidade }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

For this and work, I dont know why with select returns the error:

```
    <label for="item_unidade">item_unidade:</label>
    <input id="item_unidade" type="number" name="item_unidade" value="{{ item_unidade }}" class="number" /><br>
    <input type="submit">
```

My views.py:

```
def gerar_graficos(request):
    descricao = '01/02/2019 08:00'
    descricao2 = '01/02/2019 09:00'
    item_unidade = 0


    if request.method=='POST':
        descricao = request.POST['descricao']
        descricao2 = request.POST['descricao2']
        item_unidade = request.POST['item_unidade']


    unidade2 = ['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10','11','12','13','14','15','16','17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24','25','26','27',
                '28','29','30','31','32','33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40','41','42']



context = { 'descricao': descricao, 'descricao2': descricao2, 'passar':passar, 'unidade2':unidade2, 'item_unidade':item_unidade }
    return render(request, 'core/graficos_list.html', context)
```

Comment: please add your code of your views.py and i update my answer for you dont forget add the value for option in select..

Comment: I add the code of my views.py, and try your update, same error

Comment: the problem is that you try get the value with this: "item_unidade = request.POST['item_unidade']" and on your form has this: "inputUnidades"

Comment: I try change this and works, thank you help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change this:

```
<label for="inputUnidades">Selecione unidade</label>
<select class="form-control" id="inputUnidades">
    {% for item_unidade in unidade2 %}
    <option>{{ item_unidade }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

by this:

```
  <label for="inputUnidades">Selecione unidade</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="inputUnidades" name="inputUnidades">
        {% for item_unidade in unidade2 %}
        <option>{{ item_unidade }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Don't forget use the atribute **name** Django get the values with this don't whit the **id**.

**UPDATE:**

Don't forget add the value to the options examples:

```
<select class="form-control" name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
{% for product in product_list %}
<option value="{{ product.pk }}">{{ product.name }}</option>
{% endfor %}
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your code snippets - the working and the not working one, are the input control *name*. The *name* is what is used as the key in the dictionary passed on a POST request.

You are calling the entry `inputUnidades` in the "select" version and `item_unidade` in the "input" version - and the view code consumes the `item_unidade` in this line:

```
    item_unidade = request.POST['item_unidade']
```

(Also, you seem to have edited your code midway due to hints on the other answer - never do that - as you can break the whole answers that then become meaningless. To discuss a proposed solution that is not yet working, use the "comments", or, if needed, edit your question, but add new information to the *end* of the question. Do not change code that other people may be reviewing  and basing their answers on. The version when I started this answer did not have a `name` tag - now it is just with the incorrect name, but I had to rewrite the answer)

Try just using this:

```
 <label for="inputUnidades">Selecione unidade</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="inputUnidades" name="item_unidade">
    {% for item_unidade in unidade2 %}
    <option value="{{ item_unidade }}">{{ item_unidade }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
```

Comment: Ok, i'm new here, so i did not know that, sorry, but thanks for the answer and that works, but the preview works to so i checked his

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and that problem lies within te views.py file.

```
item_unidade = request.POST['item_unidade']
```

The above example is how I did it at first (which generated the error).

The underlying line of code fixed it for me;

```
item_unidade = request.POST.get('item_unidade', False)
```